# Venus flytrap rigging 2

Tags: rigging

I need to set the armature of the plant so I can move all of it from the head. I already made an IK that works fine to move the body of the plant the way it is intended. However the head doesnt move, except for some of the teeth of the plant (deforming the mesh in a weird way). I also need to set the armature to open or close the head of the plant but I dont know if it is possible to make all of this in the same armature.
Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1whUS_-gnd5Oj7HQHEhdVyNwGl4vWdlXm/view?usp=sharing

It would really help me if someone could do this for me, I already searched everywhere and cant find a solution. This piece is a part of a much bigger project and it has been paused due to this issue.

[image]

Comment: Hey,I'm the one from the last question of yours. Instead of parenting and choosing set automatic weight,try parenting and clicking on bone
That should stop the deformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to your fixed blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bxa8ooYTxA-37VDnpfNhYs40mXznqoRr/view?usp=sharing)

There were a lot of minor problems here that I have fixed for you, such as turning on rotation in the Ik Parameters to allow for greater control and easier animating of the flytrap. I also noticed that due to the weight painting on the stalk, when fully extended there were weird creases created. Rebaking the weight paints fixed this. I created extra bones to control the "jaws" of the flytrap, disconnected them and the teeth from the rest of the mesh, then weight painted them onto the bones. I also noticed you somehow had over 200 bone vertex weight groups. Most of them having zero effect on anything, so I made sure to delete those too. I also remeshed and retopologized quite a bit of the mesh since it had a lot of holes and unnecessary geometry. I even added a small test animation as well, good luck with your project.

Comment: wow man thank you so much! I cant see the changes in the file that you provided, could you check it please? Or maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bxa8ooYTxA-37VDnpfNhYs40mXznqoRr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank youuuu the control and the movement are exactly what I was searching for, I really apreciate the job you did. And thanks for the explanation, I now understand what I was totally missing lol

Comment: No problem, and sorry about messing up the google link lol, not sure how I manage to keep doing that.